# Return alert dialog if one/both fields are blank or contain default values

Tags: jquery

How can I return an alert dialog with an error message when the user tries to submit my form either if one/both of the fields are blank or if one/both of the fields contain default values?

Here is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<!-- idea title -->
<textarea id="ideaTitle" />Please give your idea a title...</textarea>
<br />
<!-- idea body -->
<textarea id="ideaBody" rows="5" />Please provide details of your idea...</textarea>
<br />
<!-- submit button -->
<input type="button" id="sendMessage" value="broadcast" />
```

**JS**

```
 $(function () {
     $('#ideaTitle, #ideaBody').each(function () {
         $.data(this, 'default', this.value);
     }).focus(function () {
         if (!$.data(this, 'edited')) {
             this.value = "";
         }
     }).change(function () {
         $.data(this, 'edited', this.value != "");
     }).blur(function () {
         if (!$.data(this, 'edited')) {
             this.value = $.data(this, 'default');
         }
     });
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EKmmq/

Comment: you might want to research the `placeholder` attribute for HTML input fields

Comment: @InGodITrust, I'm developing for IE6-IE9. Placeholder support is a bit iffy on those browsers

Comment: Then maybe [this plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) could help?

Comment: @methuselah check this out http://jsfiddle.net/EFNvs/

Comment: it uses a jquery placeholder plugin which i have called at the end of the code using `.placeholder()`

Comment: @koala_dev took the words from my mouth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this event handler to the button:

```
 $('#sendMessage').click(function () {
     $('#ideaTitle,#ideaBody').each(function () {
         if ($.trim($(this).val()).length === 0) {
             alert('empty');
             return false;
         }
         if ($.trim($(this).val()) === $(this).data('default')) {
             alert('default');
             return false;
         }
     })
 });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EKmmq/2/)**